# Sketching the graph of a sum of sinusoids with different frequencies

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently taking a course in signals and systems in continuous time and have a question regarding one of my practice problems.

The problem asks to sketch the graph of the following signal:

$$x(t) = \cos\left(\frac{3\pi t}{4}\right) + \sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right)$$

The way I tried sketching it was to use the curve sketching techniques from calculus, but this turned out to be fairly difficult and led to me missing a few of the features of the graph (e.g. by not finding all of the roots to the equations).

I'm not sure if I'm just missing something, but I was just wondering if there is an easier way to sketch functions of this form (combinations of sinusoids with different frequencies), or if there are any tricks to know what the underlying shape is going to be?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.